# How to add 1 to a javaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to add 1 to the value "$arate_num" and update the database with new $arate_num called "num3". But it is not working properly.

Here is my PHP code.

```
$jsqla = mysql_query("select * from products where id='$product_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$jfeta = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla);

$arate_num = $jfeta['rate_number'];
```

Here is my javaScript code.

```
var phpvalue = "<?php echo $arate_num; ?>";
var num = parseInt(phpvalue, 10);
var num3 = parseInt(phpvalue+1, 10);
alert(num3);
```

Comment: var phpvalue = "<?php echo $arate_num; ?>"; - 
you can't execute php code inside javascript!

Comment: simply do `var num3 = num+1;`

Comment: numeric? var phpvalue = "<?php echo $arate_num; ?>"; remove the quote -> var phpvalue = <?php echo $arate_num; ?>; and to not parse.

Comment: why phpvalue+1 ? You already parsed the value, just add 1 to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace:

```
var num3 = parseInt(phpvalue+1, 10);
```

With:

```
var num3 = parseInt(phpvalue, 10) + 1;
```

`phpvalue` is a string. Adding `1` to it concatenates the `1` at the end of the string.

Say, `phpvalue` is `"1337"`, `parseInt(phpvalue+1, 10)` will be `13371`, because you're parsing `"13371"`.

---

However, if you just remove the quotes from:

```
var phpvalue = "<?php echo $arate_num; ?>";
```

Like this:

```
var phpvalue = <?php echo $arate_num; ?>;
```

Then you can just use the echo'd number:

```
var num = phpvalue;
var num3 = phpvalue + 1;
```

Comment: It will be better not to parse it.

Comment: Because if you already know that a var is numeric it will be better not to lose time parsing :) you are looking at a single var, but my comments it's general. (+1 after your edit)